# DOMDocument - Remove all content of script tag

Tags: php, domdocument

I try with bellow code to remove all content of scripts in html content:

```
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML('<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">' . $html);

        $script = $dom->getElementsByTagName('script');

        $remove = [];
        foreach($script as $item)
        {
            $remove[] = $item;
        }

        foreach ($remove as $item)
        {
            $item->parentNode->removeChild($item);
        }
$dom->saveHTML();
```

The script that I try to remove is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* DO NOT MODIFY */
(function(w,d) {
  w.cdxhd = w.cdxhd || [];
  w.cdxhd.push({
    "cdxhd_bpid":158716,
    "cdxhd_w"   :300,
    "cdxhd_h"   :250,
    "cdxhd_vtag":20140808,
    "cdxhd_slot":w.cdxhd.length
  });
 d.write('<div class="cdxhd_'+cdxhd[(cdxhd.length-1)]['cdxhd_bpid']+' cdxhd_slot" id="cdxhd_bpid_'+cdxhd[(cdxhd.length-1)]['cdxhd_bpid']+'_'+cdxhd[(cdxhd.length-1)]['cdxhd_slot']+'" style="position:relative;"></div>');
 var s = d.createElement("script"); s.async = true;
 s.src = (d.location.protocol==="https:"?"https":"http")+'://ca.cubecdn.net/js/loader_v2.js?cb='+(new Date().getMinutes()+new Date().getHours());
 var a = d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]; a.parentNode.insertBefore(s,a);
}(this,document));
</script>
```

but I still get:

```
 var s = d.createElement("script"); s.async = true;\n
 s.src = (d.location.protocol==="https:"?"https":"http")+'://ca.cubecdn.net/js/loader_v2.js?cb='+(new Date().getMinutes()+new Date().getHours());\n
 var a = d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]; a.parentNode.insertBefore(s,a);\n
}(this,document));
```

The last section of script does not removed.

Is there any solution to remove all scripts and it's content without regex?